# How to set unique id for views (like button) on listview that made by simple cursor adapter in android java?

Tags: android, listview, uniqueidentifier, simplecursoradapter, android-cursoradapter

I create a dynamic custom listview that contain some elements like button ImageView and etc using custom adapter cursor adapter. this is problem when i click on any button because of  duplicate id i lost my specific button. i have set tag for each button and is correct but i can't find my button id.
Also i use "button.setID()" but is not worked in some elemnts.
How can I set unique id for views (like button) in this case?
(In the general view I want work with any element in my listview separately )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need different `button`(any view) ids... Just access the item with `Position` and find the view with ID.

**Kindly** read and understand the docs before apply..